# Stack Overflow should stop leaking information to other websites about whether we are logged in

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, privacy

For full details, see: https://robinlinus.github.io/socialmedia-leak/

In short, the following code on a third party website:

```
<img onload="alert('logged in to SO')" 
     onerror="alert('not logged in to SO')"
     src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2ffavicon.ico">
```

will call the `onload` function if you are logged in to SO, and the `onerror` function if not.  This leaks information about me to other websites.

At least Instagram has fixed this by hosting its favicon on its CDN.  I don't know if there are other solutions possible.

Comment: +1, but I don't understand the link between 'Social Media' and 'Stack Overflow'.

Comment: [Jeff Atwood on Twitter: "favicon.ico is a privacy leak"](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/786259854235009024)

Comment: @Glorfindindel SO behaves likes Social  media in some ways. I suspect this applies to any website with a login

Comment: I summarized and explained a little what made this possible. Do note I'm NOT the author of the exploit post.

Comment: You can probably do stuff to people from other sites without having them figure out what you're doing,but not those on stackoverflow.They'll decipher your codes in seconds.Must be nice to be a sofware engineer :)

Comment: SO lists on every user's public profile how long it's been since they were last on the site.  It's not an exploit when the information is freely given out to anonymous users.  You don't need to do anything fancy with a favicon, you just need to look at the profile.

Comment: @Servy There is a difference between "a specific user is online at this time", and "the active visitor has a Stack Overflow account".

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara On every user's profile it shows you when they were last online.

Comment: @Servy True, but that doesn't tell you if the person who is using the browser that just visited your website has a Stack Overflow account. That's what this hack tells you.

Comment: `You are logged in to:
No platform
(or you're using something like Privacy Badger) ` - This addon works well

Comment: Same for uBlock origin

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I'm not sure it is ever going to be *hugely* controversial to be logged into Stack Overflow, but: fixed for the current incarnations of this and a few other scenarios we could think of:

[image]

(yes, I'm logged in here)

Comment: Blimey.  That was fast!  - and yes, I agree, being logged in to SO is not that significant - but more privacy is better than less :-).

Comment: absolutely; and I think it is actually probably potentially more relevant to the SE network sites - but also good to fix it just in terms of best practice etc

Comment: The issue (as I understand it) isn't knowing whether someone is logged into SO specifically, but the ability to use it as (part of) a fingerprint of a person across the internet.

Comment: Being logged into SO itself shouldn't be controversial, nor is it for most of the other sites listed; but snooping this sort of stuff is one of the ways that scumbag advertiser companies build stealth profiles to track people without our letting them make it easier by storing cookies in our browsers.

Comment: While it may not be controversial, it gives attackers potential information about their targets. Someone logged into SO will most likely make a juicy target for someone looking to get into company networks. If this leak can be extended to the SE-admin-site then it will reveal even jucier targets.

Comment: This solution is imperfect: [Stack Overflow logged in information leak - Part 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336337/stack-overflow-logged-in-information-leak-part-2)

Answer (score 12):

### Basically a CSRF problem.

This looks like it is just a variation on a typical CSRF attack, to which there are well established solutions.

**1.** Use a CSRF token.

Automatic redirection should not take place unless a valid and client-unique token can be provided in the URL.

**2.** Detect `referer` (*imperfect*)

If the `referer` is not a white-listed domain, always show an error page. This is imperfect however, because privacy software may remove or falsify the value. It would be ugly if a privacy feature failed to protect privacy-conscious users.

**3.** Always prompt the user when logged in before continuing.

Basically this would involve removing the automatic redirect header, and adding a prompt with a dynamic link. Or a form which must also be protected by a CSRF token (which would make it the same as option 1 with an extra prompt).

P.S. If you are going to down vote this, it would be cool if you share why *the de facto solution* to a basic and reasonably well-known internet application security problem is not ideal.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This answer is correct: rather than finding and eliminating all images/CSS/JS hosted on the domain, fix the redirect page by including a CSRF token, and don't redirect unless it's valid.

Comment: @dchest I find most people simply do not understand the basics of internet security.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure whether this is really Stack Overflow's responsibility to fix, but for what it's worth this issue still exists in some browsers. Apple's default handling of third-party cookies protects Safari users, but that is at odds with Google's business model, so Chrome users are susceptible. I haven't tested others.

In addition to being able to detect if users are logged in, we can detect certain privilege thresholds based on how different URLs load. By checking a visitor's privilege levels across several sites, it may theoretically be possible to deanonymize some users. However, this isn't very practical: with the number of requests it would take, you'd need to keep the user on your page for a long time to avoid tripping Stack's rate limiting.

### Proof of Concept

```js
const canLoad = async (url) => new Promise(resolve => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.onload = () => resolve(true);
  script.onerror = () => resolve(false);
  script.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});

(async () => {
  for (const site of [
    'stackoverflow.com',
    'superuser.com',
    'gaming.stackexchange.com',
  ]) {
    output.textContent += `\n${site.padStart(24)}: `;
    if (await canLoad(`https://${site}/admin`)) {
      output.textContent += "You're a moderator or employee.";
    } else if (await canLoad(`https://${site}/site-analytics`)) {
      output.textContent += "You have at least 20k reputation.";
    } else if (await canLoad(`https://${site}/tools`)) {
      output.textContent += "You're over nine thousand.";
    } else if (await canLoad(`https://${site}/users/flag-summary/current`)) {
      output.textContent += "You have an account.";
    } else {
      output.textContent += "You're a guest.";
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

### Example Output

```
       stackoverflow.com: You have at least 20k reputation.
           superuser.com: You're a guest.
gaming.stackexchange.com: You have an account.
```

Comment: FWIW, it tells me I have an account on gaming even though I don't. /users/edit/current goes to a page asking me to confirm creating an account.

Comment: Maybe this would tap too much into your knowledge that you want to be paid for but is this fixable by SE? Or is disabling third-party cookies the only reliable way and everything else is patch-work waiting for the next "leak".

Comment: I'm not sure. My understanding is that the Origin header should let you reliably deauthenticate third-party cookies in all remotely modern browsers (like the referrer suggestion above but more consistent). If you fail open when it's absent, that shouldn't adversely impact any users (on older browsers or with privacy plugins). But I haven't actually tried to do this before, so I might be mistaken or missing something. Maybe I'll file a privacy ticket at work so I have an excuse to try it in practice.

Comment: @BSMP Fixed, I think.

Answer (score 4):

So to summarize the [linked article](https://robinlinus.github.io/socialmedia-leak/):

- The "same origin" security policy prevents you from requesting HTML from another website then the one you're currently on. This is for sites requiring a login, to prevent, for instance, a third party website scraping information displayed only to me when I'm logged in somewhere.
- The "same origin" policy does not count for images (you can request cross-origin images)
- Most images on any social sites (and stack overflow) are hosted on their CDN (Content delivery network) instead of the main site, closing off this avenue of attack
- The Website favicon is not (at least for stack overflow), enabling this attack

This means an image with this source:

```
src="https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2ffavicon.ico"
```

Will only load if the user viewing the page is logged into stack overflow. If not, the URL will instead return the HTML for the login page. This makes it possible for any third party website to access information as to whether or not a user is logged into Stack Overflow by using the `onload=""` and `onerror=""` attributes of an embedded image.

Comment: Actually, we already *do* host the favicon on the CDN - [here it is](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico) (the url in question ends up there, because historically `{domain}/favicon.ico` was the default). We are discussing options to prevent this, but it isn't as simple as "host the favicon on the CDN"

Comment: @MarcGravell Out of curiosity, which challenges need to be overcome?

Comment: Right, I removed that "potential solution" part then if thats not the issue

Comment: @Stijn deciding the "right" option, for starters; is it omitting anything that looks resource-like from the returnurl? is it doing something like using a 200 with html and a `<meta http-equiv="refresh">`  from the login page, rather than a 3** redirect? things to consider

Comment: @MarcGravell Would it be hard to return a valid favicon even if the user isn't logged in? Or a valid white box of an image? The entire exploit hinges on abuse of the `onerorr=""` property of an image, no?

Comment: @Magisch right; so what you're talking about there is detecting that they're requesting an image - which could be via the url or could be via the "Accept" header; again, all things that we're discussing. Hence my "is it omitting anything that looks resource-like from the returnurl?" comment.

Comment: @MarcGravell: "We are discussing options to prevent this" sounds like an answer to me.  "It isn't as simple as ... " - well there's a surprise (not!).

Comment: @MarcGravell Ahh, so that was what you meant. Apologies, I'm not that deep in the terminology. In the meantime, its nice that you guys are looking for a fix, because leaving this up in the long run could have some rather unpleasant side effects for SO users otherwise.

Comment: Returning a different image could present some other possible detections. For example, if the width and height are different, then you could detect that.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Can't you just prevent the return url from being the favicon?

Comment: @MarcGravell - One interesting problem with the asp.net mvc framework in general is that for favicon requests it will create erroneous sessions. In other words, you create one session for the user, and one also for the favicon request. In general this is prevented in the routing and it is suggested that the route be blocked using `routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");`. I am not sure if you are already doing that though, or are aware of this nuance. Ignoring both the request route and blocking the returnurl should present some level of protection though.

Comment: @Travis the issue is wider than that, but that is just one example of the image scenario

Comment: @Alexander the server never sees the image or the dimensions

Comment: @Travis none of this relates to MVC semantics; and as it happens, even if it did: our specific usage of MVC would still make that a non-issue

Comment: @Marc Right, but the client does. So if you were to return a different image as Magisch suggested, if the dimensions don't match, the client-side hack is still possible.

Comment: @Alexander in the scenario, the client is already hostile and probably isn't anything to do with us. Any client-side fix is irrelevant.

Comment: @Marc Perhaps we are talking about two different things. Above it was suggested that if an image were requested, and the user not authenticated, instead of an HTML response, return a dummy image. The trouble with that is, you can load and access the image size of an image loaded cross-origin. So basically, that does not work.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara we would never link to an image through login...so if we went through the trouble of determining the possible image paths (this is my preference for a fix), we'd just block *all* requests trying to redirect to such. That way you can't tell who's logged in or not...*all* of the requests error.

Comment: @TravisJ just an FYI: that favicon is a IIS level rewrite, the routing engine never sees the request. It's a very lightweight redirect. We also don't use any session functionality included in the framework. Our sessions only exists for logged in users (accounts, really, across the entire network) and are not per-request in any way.

Answer (score -8):

Disable third-party cookies in your browser. This will also stop other forms of tracking.

Disabling third party-cookies means that when you are browsing a page on `example.com`, all requests to resources belonging to `example.biz` will be done cookieless even if you have a cookie on `example.biz`.

I am not sure whether Mozilla recommends this practice or not (I **do** recommend) but [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-third-party-cookies) is an article:

Disable third-party cookies in Firefox to stop some types of tracking by advertisers

> Third-party cookies are cookies that are set by a website other than
>   the one you are currently on. For example, cnn.com might have a
>   Facebook like button on their site. That like button will set a cookie
>   that can be read by Facebook. That would be considered a third-party
>   cookie.
>
> Some advertisers use these types of cookies to track your visits to
>   the various websites on which they advertise. If you are concerned
>   about this, you can disable third-party cookies in Firefox.

Comment: Can downvoters kindly explain? Forbidding third party cookies means that requests to a protected resource will result in the login screen and the onError callback, since no cookie will be sent to the third party domain. Am I misunderstanding something? Indeed, I have suggested to do work on the user side (millions of people have to do that) instead of website-side

Comment: I believe the reason for the downvotes is that this post is intended to get SE to fix something globally, rather than as a per-client basis. Disabling third-party cookies isn't something that we can apply to 10M people automatically, where-as the global fix: is. Likewise, disabling 3rd party cookies may have unexpected other consequences.

Comment: Besides being a workaround (not fix) that each client has to opt into, it will break plenty of legitimate sites and useful features. It's not a very practical suggestion.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. But I think there is little legitimate use of third party cookies. I have personally done that to prevent unwanted (not to say unauthorized, because consent is implicit/extorted) tracking