# My logo to add a team?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

**Stop using my profile logo to add a team:**

[image]

Kidding aside...No seriously...can we change this to be a small button that says "Add".
I originally thought this was a way to "expand" my teams.  But instead it took me to create a new team.  I think a small add button would work better here.

And when it takes me to create a new team why do we lose the physical menu on the left.  In that case this should of opened `target="_blank"`?

Comment: ...waits to hear all the comments about not using freehand red circles...

Comment: And it is not even Friday! At least not for me ...

Comment: If you hover, the tool tip clearly says what the + does.

Comment: @Catija I couldn't resist: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rib2o.png ... sorry ...

Comment: A small part of me is sad that we didn't just use `&plus;` or U+002B there, with some css font boldness.  Oh well. And for your team, we'd get [all these spares for free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_and_political_symbols_in_Unicode)

Comment: @JonH Free hand circle blasphemer.

Comment: I know it's funny, but it's kind of annoying that your actual UX problem report doesn't occur until over halfway through the question. It's easy to miss your report entirely if I just skim the post. In the interest of clarity, I'd recommend putting jokes at the *end* of a post and only using jokes in the title if they don't obfuscate the actual issue at hand.

Comment: I'm not sure what 3 is pointing at?

Comment: @Shadow It's pointing at the + sign, which is a universal symbol for "add new".

Comment: @TylerH Wrong 3...

Comment: @JL2210 I knew I shouldn't have skipped math class...